# What reference is needed to Dim as Task

Tags: vba, excel

I was given a workbook that has the statement:

```
Dim tsk as Task
```

I am not familiar with the data type "Task". It does not work on my machine which leads me to believe that I need to add the proper reference for it to work. (vba/Tools/Reference/).

Does anyone know which reference "Task" is in?

Comment: Looks like MS Outlook - what does the code do?  Might help to add a little detail.  In the VBA editor go to Tools >> References and check for "missing" items

Comment: I'm actually debugging this for someone else. Im not 100% on what it does. It collects MS Outlook and MS Project data. I know a VBAProject Reference is missing, but I don't know which one. On my machine there are hundreds of available references. I've tried a few Microsoft ones (Project and Outlook) and they didnt work. I was hoping this would be obvious for someone who uses it often. I just never have used this data-type.

Comment: It's not obvious with only one declaration and no other details.  If you can post more code and some details about your environment (Office version? 32 or 64-bit?) that might get you more useful suggestions.  If you need to automate both Outlook and Project then you will need at least the references "Microsoft outlook xx.0 Object library" and "Microsoft Project xx.0 Object library". xx depends on your installed Office version.

Comment: I think this might be [what you look for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866326.aspx).

Comment: I found it. The reference is "Microsoft Project 14.0 Object Library." Originally, I tried the wrong Project reference. Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Project 14.0 Object Library.